# Ubuntu cant login as super user Authentication failure,for a previously accessed password

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, su

i cant login as super user using su command ,previously it was successful and i am sure that password is correct,previosly there was an issue by changing file permission of www folder and i follow this link to correct it http://sysadminnotebook.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-reset-folder-permissions-to.html after that i cant login as su

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, you can not login directly as root with `su` in Ubuntu. You need to run the command with the prefix `sudo`, or in your case obtain a shell with `sudo su`.

Comment: no,it is not the case,it was previously able to use su, the out put of sudo su is
"sudo: must be setuid root"

Comment: The `/usr/bin/sudo` must be setuid normally, and to do that you can run `chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo`. But since you need root access to execute this command, you are trapped. One way I see to solve this is to boot from a live cd, mount the root partition, execute this command to setuid `sudo` and reboot the system.

Comment: i have one terminal with root access opened before this operation,so i think i can do that

Answer (score 0):

You should boot into live mode, and then mount the drives and then change the permission for the file /usr/bin/sudo